# Laravel 5.3 Querybuilder

Tags: php, laravel

I have Accident and Attendance table. Accident has accident_date, driver_id. Attendance has working_date and driver_id.

The flow that I want is once I add accident and fill the accident_date field it needs to check to attendance working_date, and how many drivers working on that date and it'll show driver name by filter working only.

Ex : Attendance 11/13/2016 only 2 drivers working, once I add accident same date with attendance 11/13/2016 only those 2 drivers name will be shown/available.

here's my controller so far :

```
public function render(View $view, $route = null, $obj = null, $method = 'POST') {
    $claimTypeList = ClaimType::getArray();
    $accidentStatusList = AccidentStatus::getArray();
    $driver = Driver::pluck('first_name', 'id');
    $view->with(compact('claimTypeList', 'accidentStatusList', 'driver'));
    return parent::render($view, $route, $obj, $method);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `join` for the `$driver` query with the attendance table

```
$driver = Driver::select('first_name', 'drivers.id')
    ->join('attendances', 'attendances.driver_id', '=', 'drivers.id')
    ->where('working_date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('11/13/2016'))
    ->get();
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins)

Comment: how if the date is not 11/13 ?

Comment: it is just an example from your code. you could pass a variable of string date there. maybe could use `Request` from GET parameters when user select the date https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input